# Convert QSqlQueryModel Data into QVector(s)

Tags: c++, qt

If we get data from an SQL database using the following QT functionality

```
 QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
 model->setQuery("SELECT name, salary FROM employee");
```

it states in the accompanying material we can access individual elements using either of the following commands

```
 int salary = model.record(4).value("salary").toInt();
```

or

```
 int salary = model.data(model.index(4, 2)).toInt();
```

and that we can insert this data into a QTableView using

```
 QTableView *view = new QTableView;
 view->setModel(model);
```

And that this data can also be However, I can see anywhere how to extract a whole column of data or range of columns / rows (or as in the terminology of QSqlQueryModel index & roles).

Ultimately what I would like to do is efficiently extract parts of the data into either QVectors e.g column 3 of the data. or possibly into a matrix library such as armadillo or Eigen using some sort of getDataFunc(QVector rows, QVector columns).

The data I am working is can be huge, so efficiently is important and thus using a naive set of for loops seems a very bad idea.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look on QAbstractProxyModel. Especially considering that you've got a huge datasets, so copying them in between different places doesn't look good to me.

So in the code language I think I would create something like:

```
class RowsInColumnProxyModel: public QAbstractProxyModel {

  ....

  void setTargetColumn( int column );
  void setRowsRange(int minRow, int maxRow);

  int rowCount(..);
  int columnCount(..);

  ... whatever else on your taste from QAbstractItemModel ... 

  virtual QModelIndex   mapFromSource(const QModelIndex & sourceIndex) const;
  virtual QModelIndex   mapToSource(const QModelIndex & proxyIndex) const;
}
```

you might want to have a look in the Qt documentation, since there are plenty examples available. Idea is that inside mapFrom and mapTo functions you provide a logic which maps 
index in your column into index in full dataset, as well as proper values for rows() and columns().. rest is done automatically for you and as soon as ProxyModel is just a model you can use it in any UI controls or any other way you like. I use proxy models a lot and it's very convenient thing once you get used to it.

I will try to make some example, hope it will make things clear for you... 
A model in Qt (whatever type it has), is a set of data. Depending on type it could be either a table with rows and columns (obviously model with one column is a list), or something more advanced like tree where you could have more complex hierarchical structures, but let's leave it for now.

So, QSqlQueryModel is a flat table with rows and columns, where rows - is a number of records in result set and columns are number of columns you fetched with your query..

Let's say you've got something like

Col1    Col2    Col3

1      2       a
  4      3       v
  5      f       f

from math prospective point of view you can call it a matrix.

QModelIndex - is a class which represents a "position" in model. To make things simple you can think of it as something representing pair { row, column }

so you can fetch data from model using method

```
 QVariant data( QModelIndex, DisplayRole)
```

this method will return you a content of a cell located at position described by QModelIndex. To convert physical row and column you should use method

```
QModelIndex index(int row, int column, QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
```

you can ignore last parameter for now (it's only used on tree models), so to get any cell from the flat table model (which QSqlRecordModel is) you can use code like:

```
 QVariant value = model.data( model.index( row, column) );
 int      intValue = value.toInt();

 .. or in case you expect a string

 QString  strValue = value.toString()

 .. etc
```

so, getting close to subject... you task is to extract a vector, so lets say a part of any matrix column...so you define a class like:

```
 class Vector: public QAbstractProxyModel {
     protected:

         // make them =0 in constructor

         int        m_column;
         int        m_minRow;
         int        m_maxRow;

      ...

         void  setTargetColumn( int column ) {
            // emitting signals important to let rest of the world now about changes
            emit beginResetModel();
            m_column = column;
            emit endResetModel();
         }

         void setRowsRange( int minRow, int maxRow ) {
            // emitting signals important to let rest of the world now about changes
            emit beginResetModel();
            m_minRow = minRow;
            m_maxRow = maxRow;
            emit endResetModel();             
         }

         virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) {
            return 1;  // since it's vector
         }

         virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) {
            return m_maxRow - m_minRow;
         }

         .. now most exciting part..

         virtual QModelIndex   mapFromSource(const QModelIndex & sourceIndex) const {
             int sourceRow = sourceIndex.row();
             int sourceColumn = sourceIndex.column();

             int targetColumn = 0; // only one in vector
             int targetRow = sourceRow - m_minRow;

             return modelIndex( targetRow, targetColumn );
         }

         virtual QModelIndex   mapToSource(const QModelIndex & proxyIndex) const {
             // same as above but a bit shorter

             return index( proxyIndex.row()+m_minRow, m_column );
         }       
 }
```

ok, we've got a class let's use it

```
 QSqlRecordModel * sourceModel = ... (so, it's something)
 Vector * myVector = new Vector();
 myVector->setSourceModel( sourceModel );
 myVector->setTargetColumn(3);
 myVector->setRowsRange(5, 10);

 ...

 for (int i=0;i<myVector->rowCount();i++) {
     int vectorItem = myVector->data( myVector->index(i,0) ).toInt();
 }
```

hope it explains a bit more, what I meant with my answer

Comment: Thanks...it seems a bit advanced at this stage., as as rather new to this particular aspect of QT.

I am not even really sure how one would efficiently either access the underlying "raw" data held in a QSqlQueryModel or any other model, and how I would convert any selection to say a QVector or similar (without writing a huge loop).

Comment: OK, thanks for taking the time to provide that example...it makes things a lot clearer. I have in the meantime being doing some of my own reading and I now know that QSqlQueryModel is built until a set of QSqlQuery commands. I am wondering which is more efficient, writing a QSqlQuery (or several) to get data out the database, iterate through the results, store as QVector (or more likely a Arma:Matrix) then and there and then write own QAbstractTableModel to use with QT views or stick with QSqlQueryModel and try and get the  data out using a QAbstractProxyModel.

Comment: well its depends.. there is nothing really wrong in using QSqlQueryModel, but personally I prefer to use QSqlQuery and deal with data manually pushing then into model, that gives more control on whats actually going to/from database... it's really depends on architecture and application design

Comment: What is "modelIndex" function in "mapFromSource"?