# Qt display not all fields from Model

Tags: qt

I'm displaying the query from an QSqlModel in a table view. e.G.

```
SELECT id, name FROM person;
```

I don't want to display id in the view, however I need the id when the user clicks on a row in that view.

Is there a model in Qt, which allows me to display only specified columns in views but also providing access to invisible ones?

I used to do it by hiding the columns e.g.:

```
ui->myview->setColumnHidden( 0, true );
```

But probably there is a better solution.

Comment: Only other solution I can think of is subclassing QSortFilterProxyModel and overriding filterAcceptsColumn

Comment: So what's the problem with setColumnHidden? Or do you want to hide it from the model instead, something like model.hideColumn()?

Comment: @fxam: yes exactly! I don't want to configure each view, which displays model's data.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Looks good! Using mapToSource should give me the original row containing all the data then? I would accept it as an answer, if you'd post it.

Comment: Yes Map to source would give you the original row with all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP amended the question to exclude using `QTableView` the only alternative that would seem to work is the creation of a new class derived from `QSortFilterProxyModel`. One can override the `filterAcceptsColumn` method

Documentation on the class `QSortFilterProxyModel` can be found [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)

> QSortFilterProxyModel can be used for sorting items, filtering out items, or both. The model transforms the structure of a source model by mapping the model indexes it supplies to new indexes, corresponding to different locations, for views to use. This approach allows a given source model to be restructured as far as views are concerned **without requiring any transformations on the underlying data**, and without duplicating the data in memory.

You'd also have to override `MapToSource` and `SourceToMap` . There is a good example of usage in this StackOverflow's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128722/convert-qsqlquerymodel-data-into-qvectors/18130955#18130955)